# Overloading global && operator in Haskell fails to compile

Tags: parsing, haskell, overloading, operator-keyword

I've got a hs file, trying to overload && operator

```
(&&)::Bool->Bool->Bool
True && x = x
False && _ = False

and' :: (Bool)->Bool
and' xs=foldr (&&) True xs
```

When imported in Prelude, there's error:

```
Ambiguous occurrence ‘&&’
It could refer to either ‘Main.&&’, defined at D:\baby.hs:2:6
                      or ‘Prelude.&&’,
                         imported from ‘Prelude’ at D:\baby.hs:1:1
                         (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Classes’)
```

So I changed the last line to be

```
and' xs=foldr (Main.&&) True xs
```

Now it prints new error message:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘xs’
In the expression: foldr (Main.&&) True xs
```

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The type of `xs` should be `[Bool]` but not `(Bool)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overloading in Haskell. Identifiers can be shared using typeclasses, but `&&` is not a member of a typeclass and thus cannot be shared. When you define your own `&&` operator, it conflicts with the one automatically imported in the Prelude. To use your `&&` without qualification, you must hide `Prelude.&&` as follows:

```
import Prelude hiding ((&&))

(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True && b = b
False && _ = False
```

The second error is a mistake or typo in the type of `and'`, which should be `and' :: [Bool] -> Bool` rather than `and' :: (Bool) -> Bool`.

Answer (score 5):

As @zakyggaps said in his comment, `(Bool)` is the same as `Bool`.  You clearly mean `[Bool]`.  Also, you aren't really "overloading" this function so much as defining a similarly named one in a different module.  "Shadowing" at best, but not even that really.